# Developing a simple table

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to develop a simple table in React.js. I seen this code from a site but can not understand what this actually does.

```
var React = __webpack_require__(2);
var GridTable = __webpack_require__(5);
var GridFilter = __webpack_require__(6);
var GridPagination = __webpack_require__(7);
var GridSettings = __webpack_require__(8);
var GridNoData = __webpack_require__(9);
var CustomRowComponentContainer = __webpack_require__(10);
var CustomPaginationContainer = __webpack_require__(11);
var ColumnProperties = __webpack_require__(4);
var _ = __webpack_require__(3);
```

Does underscore has a predefined meaning or function in React.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood it,[**webpack_require**](http://webpack.github.io/docs/api-in-modules.html#__webpack_require__) is a function for requiring modules.

> **webpack_require**
>
> The raw require function. This expression isn’t parsed by the Parser for dependencies.
>
> Style: webpack

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood their question though it is still informative that link. I am however going to include the text from that link as links can expire

Comment: Well,i'm so careless.Maybe @shubham should add more  information.'_'  may mean the underscore.js?

Comment: Why do they need to add more information it's pretty clear what they are asking

Comment: thank you popeye for the answer tell me one more thing does underscore has any meaning in react or it is just a simple variable as others

Comment: @shubham In this case I'd say its just a simple variable like with any other programming language variables can start with `_` (underscores)

Comment: @shubham Indeed `_` has no React-specific meaning, it might however refer to [lodash](https://lodash.com/) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).